# Trigger Rack middleware on specific Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Is it possible to trigger Rack middleware only on specific Rails routes?

For example, let's say I wanted to run a rate limiter middleware only on the api namespace.

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 16):

I've had good success with [Rack::Throttle](https://github.com/datagraph/rack-throttle) for rate limiting. Subclass one of the built-in throttle classes and overload the `allowed?` method. Your custom logic can check which controller is being accessed and apply the rate limit as needed.

```
class ApiThrottle < Rack::Throttle::Hourly
  ##
  # Returns `false` if the rate limit has been exceeded for the given
  # `request`, or `true` otherwise.
  #
  # Rate limits are only imposed on the "api" controller
  #
  # @param  [Rack::Request] request
  # @return [Boolean]
  def allowed?(request)
    path_info = (Rails.application.routes.recognize_path request.url rescue {}) || {} 

    # Check if this route should be rate-limited
    if path_info[:controller] == "api"
      super
    else
      # other routes are not throttled, so we allow them
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `allowed?` seems to specific to `Rack::Throttle` though. For a generic approach see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096415/2771889

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Ian's answer, to setup up the ApiThrottle you have to:

```
# application.rb
require 'rack/throttle'
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.require "api_throttle"
  # max 100 requests per hour per ip
  config.middleware.use ApiThrottle, :max => 100
  ...
end

# /lib/api_throttle.rb
# Ian's code here
```

One important thing to add is that, for me, the `path_info[:controller]` came as `"api/v1/cities"` and not only as `"api"`. Of course, that is due to the namespace configuration. Therefore, take care when setting up the throttler.

Answer (score 1):

You can also (now) use a Rails Engine to create an isolated set of routes that adds additional middleware to the stack for its mounted routes.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515577/79079

(Unfortunately I found this question while looking to see if there was any simpler way to do it. Writing a custom middleware for every middleware that I wanted to add seems even more round-about than using a Rails::Engine)