# Build 2 middleware stacks in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a Rails app provides both website and api.
I don't want some elements appear in API's middleware stack, for example : `ActionDispatch::Cookies`, `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` or `ActionDispatch::Flash`.
Website's middleware stack is remain as normal.

So how could I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same situation, and wanted to do the same thing.  So far I have been able to use a Rails Engine to *add* middleware that is missing without problems for certain routes (although it is not necessarily in the "right order" in the stack, but so far it seems to be working okay):

**application.rb:**

```
# after Bundler.require(...)
require_relative '../lib/engines/website/lib/website'
```

**lib/engines/website/lib/website.rb:**

```
require_relative "website/engine"

module Website; end
```

**lib/engines/website/lib/website/engine.rb:**

```
module Website
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
    middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb:**

```
mount Website::Engine => "/website"
```

(or you can mount at "/", but [define your other routes first in that case](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#class-Rails::Engine-label-Mount+priority))

And everything for the website goes in the typical directory structure under the engine directory:

```
lib
  engines
    website
      app
        assets
          ...
        controllers
          ...
        views
          ...
      config
        routes.rb
      lib
        website
        website.rb
```

I haven't gotten very far yet, but so far this is working for me.

**Note:** Technically, the engine file doesn't even have to be a separate file in the website directory.  You could just shove it into `website.rb` and make it a one-file-wonder if there's nothing else particularly complicated to add to your lib directory.  The only requirement I've found is that the file *does* have to be in a `lib` directory inside the engine's own named directory (theoretically containing `config/routes.rb` and the rest of the engine's file structure), because when a Rails::Engine is eager-loaded by the app, the engine looks for its `lib` directory to find the adjacent [app, config, vendor, etc.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb#L35) to eager-load.