# Rails enable specify middlewares for specify route just like Phoenix pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In `phoenix framework` with pipeline we can enable specify middlewares for some route, for example:

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Router do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", HelloPhoenix do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  scope "/api", HelloPhoenix do
    pipe_through :api
  end
end
```

if request from `/api`, will only trigger `plug :accepts, ["json"]` middleware

if request from `/`, will trigger session, flash, ...etc middlewares

how to achieve this on rails, If I am using `grape` for build api and rails for build web page and enable difference middleware for each other?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @RafaelGarcia: Check out my answer. I think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike Phoenix applications, you cannot (easily) change what middleware is used for a request within Rails. The best way to get this kind of behaviour in a Rails application would be to make the controllers for a particular route inherit from a common base controller, and then define the behaviour for these particular controllers in that base controller.

Using the above example of the `/api` routes going through different "middleware", you can have a controller like this:

```
module API
  class BaseController < ActionController::API
    # things unique to API routes go here
  end
end
```

Inside this controller, you could write some `before_action` callbacks that ensure things like:

- Inbound requests are JSON only
- Requests are authenticated with a particular token

Then you can inherit from this controller for all API controllers:

```
module API
  class PostsController < API::BaseController
  end
end
```

With your regular controllers you can do all the regular things:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # things unique to non-api routes go here
end
```

And then:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
end
```

You could of course segment it more; maybe you might have another route like `/accounts/1/posts` where you have to be authenticated as the user of that account to see the posts. You can take the same approach:

```
module Accounts
  class BaseController < ActionController::Base
     # find account, check if the user is authenticated, etc.
  end
end
```

And:

```
module Accounts
  class PostsController < Accounts::BaseController
  end
end
```

---

So in summary: Rails doesn't let you do this on a routing level (easily), but you *can* accomplish the same thing at the controller level.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I was looking for was something more in this direction:

**application.rb:**

```
# after Bundler.require(...)
require_relative '../lib/engines/website/lib/website'
```

**lib/engines/website/lib/website.rb:**

```
require_relative "website/engine"

module Website; end
```

**lib/engines/website/lib/website/engine.rb:**

```
module Website
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
    middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb:**

```
mount Website::Engine => "/website"
```

And everything for the website goes in the typical directory structure under the engine directory:

```
lib
  engines
    website
      app
        assets
          ...
        controllers
          ...
        views
          ...
      config
        routes.rb
      lib
        website
        website.rb
```

Reference: [Build 2 middleware stacks in Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982663/build-2-middleware-stacks-in-rails-app/41515577#41515577)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can achieve this result by configuring Rack middleware stack, but it won't be configurable in a rails application.
Sometimes it's affordable to have unnecessary middleware for some routes.

Almost all apps that I saw are using same middleware for every request.

And yes, Phoenix behavior is better here, Rails behavior done in earliest versions, so it's hard to change something now.