# How to manage different versions a Rails API with config changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, api-versioning

I currently have a Rails 5 API with namespaced routes: `/api/v1/...`

I want to release a new version (`/api/v2/...)` that uses different authentication / CORS configurations. Specifically, v1 uses credential authentication. But in v2 I want to switch to tokens.

A quick overview of the change I want to apply for v2:

```
# Gemfile
gem rack-cors
```

```
# config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options], credentials: false
  end
end
```

Note that the `credentials` option is disabled by default. The v1 relies on this for authentication. In other words, v2 is disabling a configuration that v1 requires enabled.

I'm vary familiar with managing different configurations for different environments. But I'm interested in doing the same thing based on **routes**.

`/api/v1/...` --> configs A

`/api/v2/...` --> configs B

Is this possible? I found the [Rollout gem](https://github.com/FetLife/rollout) which seems like it *might* do what I need, but I'm not sure.

If there's a better way to approach this problem, I'm open to alternatives. The doomsday scenario is for me to stand up another instance of the API to run the new API version, but I desperately want to avoid that!

Answer (score 0):

If you want different middlewares based on routes you can either go with a Rails engine or with a regex inside your middleware. This was discussed already here [Execute Rack Middleware for Specific Routes in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096098/execute-rack-middleware-for-specific-routes-in-rails)